# Problem adding a private ip to mysql gcp instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL instance on Google Cloud. I want to whitelist an IP by adding it to the authorized network on the connections tab. When I add a new IP address in public IP to authorized networks and click on save, I receive this error:

"Operation failed: Invalid request: backup retention must be >= 1 and <= 365"

Comment: Does this happen with a newly created instance? Or on just the one in particular?

Comment: Also, something is weird, because you don't add authorized networks in private IP. That's for public IP.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, Public IP is correct. The instance was there for almost a year, I haven't change any settings recently. The only changes I made were changing GRANTS for users. 
I deleted those users, and the day after that I was able to whitelist new IP addresses.